# Let $x > 0$ and let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$. How does $f(x) = \mathbb{E}[\max\{|Z| - x, 0\}^2]$ behave?

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

Let $x > 0$ and let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$.
Define $(\cdot)_+ = \max\{\cdot, 0\}$.
Define
$$
f(x) = \mathbb{E}[(|Z| - x)_+^2] \equiv  \mathbb{E}[\max\{|Z| - x, 0\}^2].
$$
(We use the convention that the positive part binds before the square.)
I am interested in getting sharp upper and lower bounds for this function.

Using the fact that $t \mapsto t_+^2$ is convex we have
$$
f(x) \geq \Big(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} -x \Big)_+^2,  
$$
by Jensen's inequality.

Of course we also have $x_+ \leq |x|$, so that
$$
f(x) \leq 1 + x^2 - 2 x \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} = \Big(\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi} - x\Big)^2  + \frac{\pi - 2}{\pi}. 
$$
Hence, this verifies that $(\sqrt{2/\pi} - x)_+^2$ is of the correct order, up to multiplicative constants, provided that $x \in (0, x_0)$ where $x_0$ is sufficiently small.

However, these bounds will not be sharp when $x$ is growing. Any help?

Note that we have the identity
$$
f(x) = (1+x^2) \mathrm{erfc}(x/\sqrt{2}) - 2 x \phi(x)
$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the standard Normal density and $\mathrm{erfc}$ is the complementary error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did not commit calculation mistakes, we can express $f(x)$ as a function of the [error function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2):
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= 2\int_x^\infty (t-x)^2\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dt \\
   &= (1+x^2) \mathrm{erfc}(x/\sqrt{2}) - \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x e^{-x^2/2}.
\end{align*}
Now, you can refer to the literature (for example, [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8)) to choose suitable bounds for the error function.

For example, using [7.8.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8#E2), we get that
\begin{align*}
  f(x) \ge \left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x \left(x^2-\sqrt{x^2+4} x+3\right)\right) \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2 \pi}}.
\end{align*}
Using [7.8.4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8#E4), we end up with
\begin{align*}
  f(x) \le \frac{x^2-x\sqrt{x^2+8}+4}{\sqrt{x^2+8}+3 x} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}   e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} .
\end{align*}

The upper bound is sharp as $x\to\infty$ in the sense that the ratio between $f$ and the upper bound converges to $1$.

Using the [series expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.6) of the error function, we can also conclude that
\begin{align*}
  f(x) = \left(\frac{2}{x^3} - \frac{12}{x^5} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-7})\right) \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
\end{align*}
as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I think I started writing the answer before you updated the question. I have updated my answer with a lower bound using one of the inequalities from the link I provided.

Comment: @DrewBrady, is this enough, or did you have something different in mind?